# how to do i use the render function to render an image with pygame?

Tags: python, function, class, module

i keep getting this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Akinyemi/Desktop/Python/LOTR GAME/Main.py", line 21, in 
    player.render()
TypeError: render() missing 1 required positional argument: 'window'

```
import pygame

class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=60
        self.height=60
        self.velocity=0
    def update(self,gravity):
        self.velocity=gravity
        self.y-=self.velocity
    def render(self, window):
        pygame.image.load(window("m1.png")),(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error just says that the code calling the "render function is not passing in the `window` parameter.
You arenot showing that part of the code in the above listing - but there
are other broken things there: I don't konw what your passed in "window" function should return, but `pygame.image.load` take in a single string with the file location, or a file-like object (like a StringIO object). 
Second: you are separating 2 expressions by a coma inside the `render` function. While not a syntactic error this is serves nothing (it is an implicit tuple declaration), and moreover, the expression after the coma does nothing. (it is not a function call).

Maybe, if by "window" you mean the Surface object that is the display, you want this instead of the above soup:

```
def render(self, window):
    window.blit(pygame.image.load("m1.png"), (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height))
```

You have to pass the "window" argument to "render" nonetheless. Not that while this 
would work, it would be terribly inefficient, as it would load the image again
each time `render`is called. You'd better load the image in the `__init__` method,
and keep it in an `self.image` attribute.

On a side note, unless you are using is Python 3,x, your class shoult inherit from "object": `class player(object):`.